# spacing between background images parts

Tags: html, css, behavior, css3pie

```
.cornerBox {    
    background: url(../img/main-part.png) repeat-x top left ;   
    width: 400px;
    height:100px;
    border-radius: 80px;
    padding: 0 0; 
    behavior: url(PIE/PIE.htc);
}
```

In IE8 between background images parts is spacing 1px, how to remove this space, image width is `28px` I want `repeat-x`

Comment: try float:left. May be this could help.

Comment: Please provide the link of the image. need to check the image.

Comment: What happens if you remove `behavior: url(...)`?

Comment: show your code in jsfiddle.net

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/UM9Ss/ here is code and image, problem is only in IE8 ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had created a [**jsfiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/libinvbabu/QmmFy/2/) with your code, but used some other image. Tested it in IE8 and found there is no issues.

So I believe the problem may be with your `main-part.png`. The image may have a white border or something. Double check your image.

**EDIT:**

No issues with your image also. CLICK `ctrl+0` on IE to make sure you are viewing in 100%

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem with two divs with background images next to each other. I solved it by assigning:

```css
background-size: cover
```

Which stretched your image to cover the entire div